# MediaCapture SetEncodingPropertiesAsync returns exception The stream number provided was invalid. PreviewState

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a Universal Windows App for my Windows Phone (Lumia 950 with Windows 10). It's a very simple app which takes a photo using the front camera of the phone.

The problem is that the photo being taken is in landscape mode by default, which isn't great when it's a selfie. I'd like to rotate it 90 degrees so that it becomes a portrait. I use the MediaCapture object to initialize the camera. I've tried the following to rotate the image:

```
await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
var videoEncodingProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
videoEncodingProperties.Properties.Add(new Guid("C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1"), 90);
await _mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, videoEncodingProperties, null);
```

But the last line throws an exception "The stream number provided was invalid. PreviewState". I'm guessing this has to do with the GUID provided, but after countless hours googling I keep finding this value that developers use for this.

I tried another solution to rotate the image:

```
_mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
```

But that doesn't do anything.

Any ideas how I can rotate the image? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still no idea what it was? having the same problem. Seems like it happens less if you use focusControl.UnlockAsync(); before focussing

Answer (score 1):

To rotate the preview, you need an active preview. This means you need to attach the mediaCapture to your capture element, then start the preview, and finally set the rotation with SetPreviewRotation. 
If you do that, it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since pretty much nothing worked for me, I ended up re-writing most of the application in order to rotate the image. Here are the essential parts of my code that worked in the end:

```
private async void TakePicture()
    {
        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        try
        {
            await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
            var photoOrientation = _foundFrontCam ? PhotoOrientation.Rotate90 : PhotoOrientation.Normal;
            var photoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("Photo.jpeg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, photoOrientation, photoFile);                
            var imageBytes = await ShowPhotoOnScreenThenDeleteAsync(photoFile);
            PostToServerAsync(imageBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
        }
    }

private async Task ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, PhotoOrientation photoOrientation, StorageFile photoFile)
    {
        using (var inputStream = stream)
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

            using (var outputStream = await photoFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);
                var properties = new BitmapPropertySet { { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(photoOrientation, PropertyType.UInt16) } };
                await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Creating a PhotoOrientation object and passing that as part of the input stream when saving the image did the trick.

Comment: You're already doing a lot of the correct things, but for future reference, the documentation page (and accompanying GitHub sample) explain how to do this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243896.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396